# Travel reimbursement for interview (to/from airport and HOME)

Tags: interviewing, travel, reimbursement

This general question has been answered on a number of threads ([Scope of reimbursable expenses for interview](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/scope-of-reimbursable-expenses-during-an-interview?rq=1)). However, I have a specific question for this topic and didn't know whether to add it to another post or make a new one.

Most companies will reimburse flights, hotel for your trip, as well as associated rides from airport to hotel, hotel to office, office to airport. My question is whether it is generally accepted/okay to ask for ride service from my HOME to the AIRPORT (and vice versa on the return trip).

Comment: "However, I have a specific question for this topic and didn't know whether to add it to another post or make a new one." - don't add it to another existing questions. The stack exchange sites don't work well if you add new questions to existing questions.

Comment: If you leave your own car at the airport, are you reimbursed for parking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is acceptable to ask. Whether they'll agree or not - depends on company policy.

Also, as mentioned in the linked  answer, before asking, double check the details already provided to you, whether the answer is already available or not.

Answer (score 6):

In theory, it costs nothing to ask. The worst that could happen is they say "no".

However, were I in that situation, my view would be as follows:

If the company will reimburse me for travel expenses they will tell me - and they will spell out exactly what is covered. If they don't tell me a cab to/from the airport on my side is included, I'm going to assume that's because their internal finance policy does not cover it.

I then have 2 choices. I can swallow the cost myself- justifying this decision by the fact it's not a huge amount relative to the potential salary on offer. (You have to spend money to make money!)  Or I can take a chance that they've forgotten to mention this (unlikely IMO), ask them to confirm and *maybe* save myself some money. My concern would be that in doing so I would paint myself as somebody who would be a demanding, high maintenance employee, who's never happy with anything the company do. However accurate that is, I don't want them to have their decision made before I even set foot in their premises.

That's just my 2c.